# Navigation and Reloading of Angular Page

Tags: angular

I want to go navigate to certain page after button click. I need to reload the page compulsorily.
one way would be, add a flag in localstorage,navigate to that page and reload page based of value of that flag.
If i do,

```
this.router.navigate(['./dashboard']);
location.reload()
```

or

```
location.reload() 
this.router.navigate(['./dashboard']);
```

in current page, this will navigate but come back to the same page because  location.reload() reloads current page if i am not wrong.

Is there a way to listen to location.reload() so it will finish up and then i can navigate to another page? or any better way? Thanks in advance

Comment: `location.reload()` isn't part of Angular. If you call it, you destroy the current instance of your application and your re-launch a new one. Are you sure it is what you want ?

Comment: I need reload of page because I have a common layout component which has to be refreshed as I am storing some values in local storage on button click and getting it back in the common layout page. I am not sure how to do that without reloading of page.

Comment: Can you provide the code for those pieces? You shouldn't need to do a hard reload of the page.

Comment: With Subjects from RxJS, and a service.